# Calculations does not show same results between C# and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, double, rounding, calculation

I am trying to convert code from C# to javascript.

I have done those 2 testfunctions where I do a calculation in a loop. The orignal code is the C# code. But it seems that the calculations doesn't show the same results.

It has to do with how floats, doubles and rounding behaves. But I can't figure out what is going wrong.

My question should then be how can we convert this C# code to javascript to produce the same results?

In the loop cycle: 100-102 as seen below, they start to show different results:
**C#

1.5E-08___100

3.01E-08___101

4.53E-08___102**

**javascript

1.500000000000002e-8___100

1.505e-08___101

1.51e-08___102**

C# code

```js
void csharpfunction() {

    double TESTNUMBER = 0; List<double> procentLIST = new List<double>(); 
    for (double i = 0; i < 300; i += 0.5) { procentLIST.Add(i); }
    TESTNUMBER = Convert.ToDouble("0.00000001"); 

    for (int t = 0; t < procentLIST.Count; t++)
    {
        TESTNUMBER = TESTNUMBER * (1 + (procentLIST[t] / 100)); 
        listBox1.Items.Add(TESTNUMBER.ToString() + "___" + t);

        TESTNUMBER = Math.Round(TESTNUMBER, 8);
    }
}
```

Javascript Code

```js
function javascriptfunction() {

    var TESTNUMBER = 0; var i; var t; var procentLIST = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 300; i += 0.5) { procentLIST.push(i); }
    TESTNUMBER = ConvertToDouble("0.00000001"); 

    for (t = 0; t < procentLIST.length; t++) {

        TESTNUMBER = TESTNUMBER * (1 + (procentLIST[t] / 100)); 
        console.log(TESTNUMBER, "_____", t);

        TESTNUMBER = MathRound(TESTNUMBER, 8);
    }
}
function ConvertToDouble(x) {
    return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(16);
}
function MathRound(num, nrdecimals) {
    nrdecimals = Math.pow(10, nrdecimals);
    return Math.floor(num * nrdecimals) / nrdecimals; 
}
```

Comment: This is likely to be a confusion of types, like getting strings when you wanted a number, or errors in JS’s floating point math.

Comment: I think I simply like to understand how it would be possible to write that C# function for javascript. It has to be possible in any way. I also beleive it has to be a confusion of types somehow.

Comment: You really shouldn't use basic js for math as you are most likely going to encounter floating point math errors. Maybe check out something like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal.js

Comment: 64-bit floats are accurate to 14 or 15 significant digits.  You are outputting the number before you round it off.  The "difference" is outside the precision of 64-bit floats in any language/platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.toFixed` method to round to a precision. Your `MathRound` method returns different values.

```js
function javascriptfunction() {
    var TESTNUMBER = 0; var i; var t; var procentLIST = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 300; i += 0.5) { procentLIST.push(i); }
    TESTNUMBER = ConvertToDouble("0.00000001"); 

    for (t = 0; t < procentLIST.length; t++) {

        TESTNUMBER = TESTNUMBER * (1 + (procentLIST[t] / 100)); 
        console.log(TESTNUMBER.toExponential(2), "_____", t);

        TESTNUMBER = +TESTNUMBER.toFixed(8);
    }
}

function ConvertToDouble(x) {
    return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(16);
}

javascriptfunction()
```

Comment: Yes, that did actually work there when rounding using the .toFixed(8). Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: 102 is logging `4.5299999999999995e-8_____102` not `4.53e-8___102`

Comment: @ChrisBrownie55 use `.toExponential` (updated the code)

Comment: toFixed() doesn't round, it displays only (returns a string). Example: `parseFloat((1.005).toFixed(5)).toPrecision(18)` returns `"1.00499999999999989"` -- and you see, and didn't round anything.

Comment: @Wiimm `1.00499999999999989.toFixed(3)` returns `1.005`

Comment: @ajaiJothi It returns the string `"1.005"`, but not the number. Or in other words: The **number** 1.005 does not exists due to the binary representation of floats. So there can't exists any function, that is rounding any other number to exact 1.005. And that is the reasons, that `toFixed()` returns a string and not a number.

Answer (score 0):

the fragment

```csharp
TESTNUMBER = Math.Round(TESTNUMBER, 8);
```

is using **MidpointRounding.ToEven** rounding while your function

```js
function MathRound(num, nrdecimals) {
    nrdecimals = Math.pow(10, nrdecimals);
    return Math.floor(num * nrdecimals) / nrdecimals; 
}
```

does rounding down